# How to find the max date that's less than the record date in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to pull the latest date a strategy was reconstituted, before the date of the record. The strategies were reconstituted on dates where the 'reconType' is not NA. Apologies if this question has been answered already, I've been searching for a couple days but haven't been able to find anything.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
strategy <- rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), each = 3)
date <- rep(c(as.Date("2023-01-02"), as.Date("2023-01-03"), as.Date("2023-01-04")), times = 3)
reconType <- c('Annual','NA','NA','Annual','Annual','NA','NA','Annual','NA')


df1 <- data.frame(strategy, date, reconType)

df1$lastDate <- max(df1$date[!is.na(df1$Recon.Type) &  df1$date < df1$date & df1$strategy == df1$strategy])
print(df1)

  strategy       date reconType lastDate
1        a 2023-01-02    Annual     <NA>
2        a 2023-01-03        NA     <NA>
3        a 2023-01-04        NA     <NA>
4        b 2023-01-02    Annual     <NA>
5        b 2023-01-03    Annual     <NA>
6        b 2023-01-04        NA     <NA>
7        c 2023-01-02        NA     <NA>
8        c 2023-01-03    Annual     <NA>
9        c 2023-01-04        NA     <NA>
```

But what I want is:

```
 strategy       date reconType lastDate
1        a 2023-01-02    Annual     <NA>
2        a 2023-01-03        NA     2023-01-02
3        a 2023-01-04        NA     2023-01-02
4        b 2023-01-02    Annual     <NA>
5        b 2023-01-03    Annual     2023-01-02
6        b 2023-01-04        NA     2023-01-03
7        c 2023-01-02        NA     <NA>
8        c 2023-01-03    Annual     <NA>
9        c 2023-01-04        NA     2023-01-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `lag` for the condition and then `fill` to complete the group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(strategy) %>% 
  mutate(lastDate = ifelse(lag(reconType) == "Annual", as.character(lag(date)), NA)) %>% 
  fill(lastDate, .direction="down") %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  strategy date       reconType lastDate  
  <chr>    <date>     <chr>     <chr>     
1 a        2023-01-02 Annual    NA        
2 a        2023-01-03 NA        2023-01-02
3 a        2023-01-04 NA        2023-01-02
4 b        2023-01-02 Annual    NA        
5 b        2023-01-03 Annual    2023-01-02
6 b        2023-01-04 NA        2023-01-03
7 c        2023-01-02 NA        NA        
8 c        2023-01-03 Annual    NA        
9 c        2023-01-04 NA        2023-01-03
```